# expectation of a function of random variable

Tags: probability, expected-value, gamma-distribution

I have a gamma(a,b) random variable X. Under what condition can I write $E(f(X)) = f(E(X))$?
Here I have a continuous and bounded $f:(0, \infty) \to \mathbb{R}$.

Comment: In general, if $f$ is the sum of a constant function and a linear function.  Otherwise, typically not.

Comment: Generally $f$ would have to be a Linear Transformation.  Else you require $\dfrac{b^a}{\Gamma(a)}\int_0^\infty f(x)x^{a-1}\exp(-b x)\mathrm d x=f(a/b)$ .